# Getting a list of variables from a function in python

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy

I'm working on a project related urban public space.

With the following function I got an array related to a raster band of an urban environment.

```
#array generation function
def shade_array (index):
    altitude = df.altitude[index]
    azimut = df.azimut[index]
    shade = es.hillshade(elevation, azimuth = azimut, altitude = altitude)
    return shade
```

Now I want to iterate the function for a different days an hour from a dataframe.
I run the following for-loop:

```
for i in df.index:
    shade_array(i)
```

The point is that what I need is to store the info in a list of variables, like:

```
array_list = [array_01, array_02,..., array_365]
```

to cross and make some transformations in the values obtained.
How can I get to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to store data as a list of variables, just use list method `append()` that will append the passed object `shade_array(i)` into the existing list `array_list`:

```
array_list = []  
for i in df.index:
    array_list.append(shade_array(i))
```

or an even more concise approach may be to use [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) as in usr2564301's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Create the list *while* you are executing that function:

```
array_list = [shade_array(i) for i in df.index]
```